# Not able to push my data in an json server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, react-hooks, json-server

This is a local JSON server you can see on this URL
[http://localhost:3003/CourseList/1](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.e09cb2f612284a47a28c71a2c813da80)
My hooks

```
 const [subjectName,setsubjectName]=useState(
          {
            id: "",
            subjectname: "Aptitude",
            chapter: [
              {
                chapter1: "",
                topic: [
                  {
                    topic1: ""
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
    );
```

function when I click on add button which will check if it matches the id of a prop then it will perform the task

```
 const addSubject = async id => {
        console.log("id "+id);
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3003/CourseList/`)
      .then((res)=>{
        res.data.map((list,index)=>{
         if(list.id===props.id){
           console.log(list.subject)
           list.subject.push(subjectName);
          
        }
        })
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
       console.log(error);
      })
      };
```

How can I push new data in the subject array? I am getting nothing

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: No error in the console i have edited the qs please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution

const addSubject = async id => {
console.log("id "+id);

```
    try{
      const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:3003/CourseList")
      
      data.map(async(item)=>{
        if(item.id===id){
          console.log(item);
          item.subject.push(subjectName);
          
          await axios.put(`http://localhost:3003/CourseList/${id}`,item)
        }
      })
      const check= await axios.get(http://localhost:3003/CourseList/${id})
      console.log(check)
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a JSON-server it should have a default endpoint for `PATH/PUT` your new object. You need to send the `Content/Type: application/json` in your request header and set the `jsonServer.bodyParser` in your server.